# Still having problem with imported text from my database to Android

Tags: android, formatting, textview

I have had a problem with formattings symbols shown on the image. I got help from this site and I used `Html.fromHtml()` and hope that it would use the formatting, the only thing it did was to remove the formatting symbol but not anything else like newline or so.

If I cant find a way to use the formatting I wonder if it is possible to add a "\n" everytime the symbol is shown. The thing is if I try to use a method like 
(Ps the "[]" is used here instead of the real symbol cause I cant find out how to write it.

```
int nr=theTextString.indexOf("[]") 

and then replace the text with 

theTextString=theTextString.substring(0,nr)+ "\n" + theTextString.substring(nr);
```

but the problem is that the symbol is not represented as a character to look for the index at, not in any way I know of. Would really be thankful for help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `[]` crap character is only shown on the last chacter do this

```
Log.i("My String before:", theTextString);
theTextString = theTextString.substring(0, theTextString.length()-2);
Log.i("My String after:", theTextString);
```

Btw: `[]` <-- is not the same character (Infact, there are two characters) it is something else.

Solution: To encode the string

```
theTextString = URLDecoder.decode(theTextString, HTTP.UTF-8);
```

Comment: It is not the last character in the string, it is on many places in the string. reason for using [] on the example is to show something that looks simular.

Comment: Try removing concatenation with "\n"

Comment: Reason I want to insert "\n" in the string instead of the "[]" sign is because I believe "[]" is a Formatting code for "return", the problem is that I cant find out how to seek for and replaceing the symbol with a "\n".

Comment: Try decoding it. It can be anything. It can be tab it can paragraph, some strange letter.

Comment: Log you string like this `Log.i("My decoded string", URLDecoder.decode(theTextString, HTTP.UTF-8));` and see whats the output

Comment: I tried to use the decoding and it gave no comments on the symbol or even detected it, some logcat lines were just shown as blank lines without any info, guess it was where the sumbol is.

Comment: Then use `theTextString = URLDecoder.decode(theTextString, HTTP.UTF-8)` and you are done :D I hope so :D

Comment: This is fantastic, it did help to format the text but it still  had the signs, but I installed it on my phone anyway and on the phone the symbols doesnt show. The emulator and the phone doesnt show the same, thank you for the help and hope I havent wasted your time on this

Comment: Not at all. As long as it helps, no problem for me. :D Keep the good work up.